# Proof that $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$ forms a valid $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ using Boolean algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to proof that $\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$ forms a valid $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, if $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ are both each a valid $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, using Boolean algebra. Here is my attempt:

Since by definition, a $\sigma$-algebra is a **nonempty** collection of subsets, closed under:

- complement
- countable union

we can separate the following three cases:

1. The collection of subsets that comprise $\mathcal{A}_1$ intersected with the collection of subsets that comprise $\mathcal{A}_2$ results in nothing but {$\varnothing$}. Since {$\varnothing$} is part of every $\sigma$-algebra, it is a valid $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.
2. The collection of subsets that comprise $\mathcal{A}_1$ intersected with the collection of subsets that comprise $\mathcal{A}_2$ is equal to that of $\mathcal{A}_1$, so (($\mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$) == $\mathcal{A}_1$). Since $\mathcal{A}_1$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ by starting statement, the intersect must be as well.
3. For every other case:

Since the collection of subsets that comprise a $\sigma$-algebra are closed under complement, $\overline{\mathcal{A}_1}$ and $\overline{\mathcal{A}_2}$ must both be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.

Since the collection of subsets that comprise a $\sigma$-algebra are closed under union, $\overline{\mathcal{A}_1} \cup \overline{\mathcal{A}_2}$ must be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.

Since that must be closed under negation as well, $\overline{\overline{\mathcal{A}_1} \cup \overline{\mathcal{A}_2}}$ must be a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$.

$\overline{\overline{\mathcal{A}_1} \cup \overline{\mathcal{A}_2}} = \mathcal{A}_1 \cap \mathcal{A}_2$, proving our target.